# Probability for individual elements

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

I have Probability equation given by $p(r)=\frac{ (1-\alpha) \alpha^{CW}} { 1- \alpha^{CW} }. \alpha^{-r} $ .  Here r is number of objects from 1 to $CW$.

How can i write probability of picking any one of the elements from $r= 1,......,CW$ , here $CW=10$.

If it were uniform distribution we could write it as $p=1/CW=1/10$, but here every element has different probability due geometric truncated distribution equation shown above.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you are asking? $p(r)$ is a discrete probability distribution, since $\sum_{r=1}^{CW}p(r) = 1$. So, you can think of a random variable $X$ which can assume the values $X=1,\ldots , CW$ with the corresponding probabilities $P(X=r)=p(r)$.

Comment: The question is unclear. The natural interpretation of the first paragraph is that $p(r)$ is already the desired probability of picking one of the elements from $1$ to $CW$; thus it's unclear what you're asking for in the second paragraph.